# function with 2 variables

Tags: calculus

we have the next function:
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  \frac{xe^{-y^{2}}}{y} \ y \neq 0  \\ \ c \ \ \ \ y=0 \end{matrix}\right.$$ 
Is there c that f(x, y) is continuous function because of him?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Consider a multivariate function $f :\mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R.$ $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0\in \mathbb R^N$ if $f(x_0)=a$ is defined and for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for any $|| x-x_0||<\delta$ : $|a-f(x)|<\epsilon.$

Let $N=2 $ and take two different sequences approaching $(0,0)$. $(x_n,mx_n)$ and $(x_n,m'x_n);$ $n=1,2,\cdots.$ If $\lim _{n\rightarrow 0}x_n=0$ then both sequences can get any close to $(0,0)$. We say that the one sequence is approaching $(0,0)$ along the line $y=mx$ and the other one is approaching $(0,0)$ along the line $y=m'x$. For any $\delta>$ both sequences can get closer to $(0,0)$ than any $\delta>0$.

As exemplified by the example below the limit of $f$ may depend on the path we approach $(0,0)$. So there is no limit at $(0,0)$, i.e. the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

If we approach the point $(0,0)$ along the straight $y=mx$ then the limit of the function depends on $m$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-m^2x^2}}{m}=\frac{1}{m}.$$

So, there is no constant $c$ for the value of the function at $(0,0)$ securing continuity. (A constant $c$ cannot equal $\frac{1}{m}$ for many different $m$.)

Comment: thank you for your answer,  but i didn't  understand why y=mx and why only $ x \to 0 $ without y?

Comment: @BlessYourKarma: I am going to edit my answer in few minutes.

Comment: @BlessYourKarma: I've edited my answer.